# standard input in C with enough memory

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I am developing a program that receives a command (which refers to a function) and its respective arguments from STDIN. For example: `add 2 3`. I thought of entering `"add 2 3"` as an array of characters, but I wanted to know if there is any way to allocate just enough memory for each input, so as not to waste memory, or that memory is insufficient.

Comment: Instead of describing code and asking us if it's OK, please show the code.  In general, you can't know how big the input will be until you finish reading it.

Comment: I would do the following: Use a fixed-size array of a generous size (maybe 200 characters) for the actual input from `stdin`, and then, once you know the exact size and want to store the string, you can dynamically allocate a buffer of the exact required size using `malloc`, and copy the string using `strcpy`. An alternative would be to also allocate the big array using `malloc` and then to resize it to the minimum required size using `realloc`.

Comment: If you are using less than 4 KiB for the buffer to read the input, you are being silly and scrimping where you don't need to.  Even on an embedded system, it is unlikely that 256 bytes would stress your system.  Don't be so concerned about memory.  Don't be profligate, but don't be penny-wise and pound-foolish.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, I will try all the solutions. And sorry for the writing (i dont speak english very well)and  some errors, it is my first post. Thank you!

Comment: @LucasAbruzzo Note that wen you say "I thought of entering "add 2 3" as an array", it is more likely "I thought of entering "add 2 3\n" as an array". `'\n'` are characters too.  Research `fgets()`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using POSIX, you can use [`getline`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) to read line(s) of input and allocate memory:

```
char *line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
while (getline(&line, &len, stdin) > 0) {
    // read a line of input into line
    ... do something with it
}
free(line);
line = NULL;   // in case we want to use it again
```

This will allocate memory as needed to hold the line read (reusing the same memory for each subsequent line, so if you want to save a line you'll need to copy it).  It might allocate more than is needed for a line, but you can see how much it actually allocated in `len`

Comment: Just don't forget to `free()` the `line` when you are done using it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer is very useful. I would like to be able to rate it, but apparently, I have to have more "reputation" (15)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: What happens when you call `getline()` after `free()`?

Comment: @Joshua undefined behavior if you don't reset `line=NULL` after `free()` and before the next `getline()`.

Comment: sorry -- C++isms creeping in -- should be `0` or `NULL` for C

Answer (score 0):

The typical way this is done is by using a growing buffer that doubles when full. This way you will use at most 2x the amount of memory you need. Even in the DOS days we didn't allocate exactly enough. That would have been disastrous.

```
char *getline()
{
    static char *buf;
    static size_t bufsiz;
    if (!bufsiz) { buf = malloc(16); if (!buf) return buf; /* ERROR */ bufsiz = 16; }
    size_t n = 0;
    int c;
    while ((c = getc(stdin)) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        buf[n++] = c;
        if (n == bufsiz) {
            char *newbuf = realloc(buf, bufsiz << 1);
            if (!newbuf) return NULL;
            buf = nebuf;
            bufsiz <<= 1;
        }
    }
    buf[n] = 0;
    return buf;
}
```

Comment: You forgot a `buf = newbuf;` statement when `realloc()` returns success. `realloc()` will not update `buf` to point at the new memory. It should also be noted that if the caller calls `free()` on the returned `char*` it will be disastrous for this code since `buf` is a local `static` that won't be reset to `NULL` on the `free()`. On the other hand, because `buf` is a local `static`, it can never be `free()`'d thus it will leak at program exit.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Show me a platform that doesn't free memory allocated by `malloc()` on program exit.

Comment: @Joshua I didn't say the memory wouldn't be freed at all.  Obviously, the OS will reclaim the memory when the process terminates. But, the memory won't be freed under application control. For instance, if the app is using a custom memory allocator that reports memory leaks, this code WILL have a leak reported.

Comment: A weakness to this `getline()` is that the caller has extra work to do to distinguish end-of file from an empty line.  (Checking `feof()`) `fgets()` and POSIX `getline()` both return a different value between end-of-file and `"\n"`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Check `feof(stdin)` or check `errno`. Choose your poison.

Comment: @Joshua The posted code nor std C functions here are specified by C to set `errno`.  Perhaps you are thinking of some implementation specific functionality?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: With this one, you check `feof` to find end of file; with the stock `getline` you need to check `errno` instead to distinguish between IO failure and out of memory.